# How to validate rdf:type in engine.validateNodesAgainstShape

Tags: shacl

In [TopQuadrant shacl](https://github.com/TopQuadrant/shacl) 1.3.2, I'm trying to use

```
engine.validateNodesAgainstShape(focusNodes, shape.asNode());
```

with shape graph:

```
bds:PersonNameShape  a  sh:NodeShape ;
    rdfs:label      "Person Name Shape"@en ;
    sh:property     bds:PersonNameShape-personNameLabel ;
    sh:targetClass  bdo:PersonName .

bds:PersonNameShape-personNameLabel
    a               sh:PropertyShape ;
    sh:datatype     rdf:langString ;
    sh:description  "this Person has a name given by the label."@en ;
    sh:maxCount     1 ;
    sh:minCount     1 ;
    sh:path         rdfs:label .
```

and data graph:

```
bdr:P707  a              bdo:Person ;
    bdo:hasFather        bdr:P705 ;
    bdo:hasParent        bdr:P705 ;
    bdo:isRoot           true ;
    bdo:kinWith          bdr:P705 ;
    bdo:note             bdr:NT08B650B715F414F1 ;
    bdo:personEvent      bdr:EVFD910DBE53BCE208 , bdr:EVD4758367CFC1276C ;
    bdo:personGender     bdr:GenderMale ;
    bdo:personName       bdr:NM0895CB6787E8AC6E , bdr:NM2463D933BA1F9A38 ,
                         bdr:NMEA2B380AF0BBFB1B , bdr:NMC2A097019ABA499F ;
    bdo:personStudentOf  bdr:P705 ;
    skos:prefLabel       "dri med 'od zer/"@bo-x-ewts ;
.

bdr:NMC2A097019ABA499F
    a           bdo:PersonPrimaryName ;
    rdfs:label  "dri med 'od zer/"@bo-x-ewts ;
.

bdr:NM0895CB6787E8AC6E
    a           bdo:PersonPrimaryTitle ;
    rdfs:label  "sprul sku dri med/"@bo-x-ewts ;
.

bdr:NM2463D933BA1F9A38
    a           bdo:PersonPrimaryTitle ;
    rdfs:label  "bdud 'joms gter sras dri med 'od zer/"@bo-x-ewts ;
.

bdr:NMEA2B380AF0BBFB1B
    a           bdo:PersonGterStonTitle ;
    rdfs:label  "pad+ma 'gro 'dul gsang sngags gling pa/"@bo-x-ewts ;
.
```

The `focusNodes` and `shape` are:

```
validating facets: 
    [http://purl.bdrc.io/resource/NM0895CB6787E8AC6E, 
     http://purl.bdrc.io/resource/NMEA2B380AF0BBFB1B, 
     http://purl.bdrc.io/resource/NMC2A097019ABA499F,
     http://purl.bdrc.io/resource/NM2463D933BA1F9A38] 
against shape: 
    http://purl.bdrc.io/ontology/shapes/core/PersonNameShape
```

I was expecting to get a validation report showing violations of `PersonNameShape` owing to there not being any statements in the data graph indicating that, for example:

```
bdo:PersonPrimaryTitle rdfs:subClassOf bdo:PersonName .
```

but, I get an empty report:

```
[ a       sh:ValidationReport ] .
```

If I modify one of the PersonName resources to use `skos:prefLabel` instead of `rdfs:label`, then I get an expected violation result:

```
[ a          sh:ValidationReport ;
  sh:result  [ a                             sh:ValidationResult ;
               sh:focusNode                  bdr:NMC2A097019ABA499F ;
               sh:resultMessage              "Property needs to have at least 1 values, but found 0" ;
               sh:resultPath                 rdfs:label ;
               sh:resultSeverity             sh:Violation ;
               sh:sourceConstraintComponent  sh:MinCountConstraintComponent ;
               sh:sourceShape                bds:PersonNameShape-personNameLabel
             ]
] .
```

I had thought that the `sh:targetClass  bdo:PersonName` in the `PersonNameShape` declaration was part of validation but apparently [Shacl spec 2.1.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl/#targets):

> Targets of a shape are ignored whenever a focus node is provided directly as input to the validation process for that shape.

is indicating part of why I'm not seeing the expected (hoped for) violations. So my question is how do I specify that part of validation should be to check that the `rdf:type` of each of the `focusNodes` is a (`rdfs:subClassOf*`) `bdo:PersonName`.

I tried adding `sh:property     bds:PersonNameShape-personNameType ;` to `PersonNameShape` with:

```
bds:PersonNameShape-personNameType
    a               sh:PropertyShape ;
    sh:class        bdo:PersonPrimaryTitle ;
    sh:description  "type class."@en ;
    sh:maxCount     1 ;
    sh:minCount     1 ;
    sh:path         rdf:type .
```

I expected to see violations for `bdr:NMC2A097019ABA499F` and `bdr:NMEA2B380AF0BBFB1B` but the other two should validate I thought since they have `rdf:type`, `bdo:PersonPrimaryTitle`. However, I see violations that I don't understand:

```
[ a          sh:ValidationReport ;
  sh:result  [ a                             sh:ValidationResult ;
               sh:focusNode                  bdr:NM2463D933BA1F9A38 ;
               sh:resultMessage              "Value must be an instance of bdo:PersonName" ;
               sh:resultPath                 rdf:type ;
               sh:resultSeverity             sh:Violation ;
               sh:sourceConstraintComponent  sh:ClassConstraintComponent ;
               sh:sourceShape                bds:PersonNameShape-personNameType ;
               sh:value                      bdo:PersonPrimaryTitle
             ] ;
  sh:result  [ a                             sh:ValidationResult ;
               sh:focusNode                  bdr:NMC2A097019ABA499F ;
               sh:resultMessage              "Value must be an instance of bdo:PersonName" ;
               sh:resultPath                 rdf:type ;
               sh:resultSeverity             sh:Violation ;
               sh:sourceConstraintComponent  sh:ClassConstraintComponent ;
               sh:sourceShape                bds:PersonNameShape-personNameType ;
               sh:value                      bdo:PersonPrimaryName
             ] ;
  sh:result  [ a                             sh:ValidationResult ;
               sh:focusNode                  bdr:NMEA2B380AF0BBFB1B ;
               sh:resultMessage              "Value must be an instance of bdo:PersonName" ;
               sh:resultPath                 rdf:type ;
               sh:resultSeverity             sh:Violation ;
               sh:sourceConstraintComponent  sh:ClassConstraintComponent ;
               sh:sourceShape                bds:PersonNameShape-personNameType ;
               sh:value                      bdo:PersonGterStonTitle
             ] ;
  sh:result  [ a                             sh:ValidationResult ;
               sh:focusNode                  bdr:NM0895CB6787E8AC6E ;
               sh:resultMessage              "Value must be an instance of bdo:PersonName" ;
               sh:resultPath                 rdf:type ;
               sh:resultSeverity             sh:Violation ;
               sh:sourceConstraintComponent  sh:ClassConstraintComponent ;
               sh:sourceShape                bds:PersonNameShape-personNameType ;
               sh:value                      bdo:PersonPrimaryTitle
             ]
] .
```

I imagine this is a simple lack of understanding on my part, but I'm not seeing it.

Thanks in advance.